# Windows 10 detects second monitor but it has no signal

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I converted my old monitor from RGB to DVI in order to use it as a second monitor, and Windows 10 detects the monitor very well.

[On Nvidia Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIQ1s.png)
[On Windows 10 Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wpE0.png)

Also, on the screenshot, an extended screen appears well.

[On the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNr6O.jpg)

However, on the second monitor, it says 'no signal'.

So, I tried,

1. reboot PC several times
2. reconnect the cable several times
3. turn on and off the monitor several times

but none of these does work.

Is there any solution for this situation?

ps. My CPU is Ryzen 3700X and the Graphic card is GTX 1660 Super.

Comment: We're missing crucial information: monitor model and how you've converted it.

Comment: @gronostaj Monitor model is LG L1915S, and I converted it using DVI-RGB gender.

Comment: Only a DVI-I port can output an analog VGA signal.  Your DVI port is most likely a DVI-D and can only output a digital signal.  A passive DVI>VGA(RGB) adapter does not convert digital to analog.  You would need an active digital to analog converter with it's own power supply to connect your VGA monitor to your graphics adapter and have it work.